# TypeError: Uncaught error: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: node.js, swagger, hapi.js, hapi-swagger

I am using `Hapi-Swagger` to create api documentation. This is my manifest file.

```
const manifest = {
  $meta: 'Our main server manifest',
  server: {},
  connections: [
    AppConfig.get('/server')
  ],
  registrations: [
    { plugin: 'hapi-auth-jwt2' },
    { plugin: 'inert' },
    { plugin: 'vision' },
    { plugin: {
      register: 'hapi-swagger',
      options: AppConfig.get('/api')
    }
    }, {
      plugin: {
        register: 'good',
        options: AppConfig.get('/logging')
      }
    }, {
      plugin: {
        register: './auth',
        options: AppConfig.get('/auth')
      }
    },
    {
      plugin: {
        register: './hapi-rate-limit',
        options: AppConfig.get('/ratelimit')
      }
    }, {
      plugin: {
        register: './socket'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So when I am opening `/documentation` page I am getting error

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error 
    TypeError: Uncaught error: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'module.exports.internals.Any'
    --- property '_currentJoi' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: I've seen this when using old versions of hapi, e.g. hapi 17 and hapi-swagger 9. When updating to a later version (e.g. hapi/hapi 18 and hapi-swagger 11) it stopped showing up.

Comment: Can you share the options you pass to hapi-swagger, e.g. with `AppConfig.get('/api')`?

Comment: @TasosK. You are right. Updating the versions made it. Thanks